# Apple Push Notifications To Connect to App

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am building an app that has a feature of requiring logins whenever the user goes in and out of the app (seems like overkill, but it is necessary).  I am doing this in the applicationDidBecomeActive: method of the AppDelegate, which pops up a login modal view whenever the method is called.  The app also creates push notifications, and I recently noticed that whenever the user enters the app via a push notification, they can bypass the whole login process. Not exactly sure if this is some bug in the app or because app entry through push notifications is not calling the applicationDidBecomeActive:.

How do push notifications interact with an app when they are selected?

Answer (score 1):

When an user enter through a push notification, a special method gets called, implement that method to detect if they came from the background:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:      (NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
{
     //came from background, show the login screen
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now! I'll implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applicationDidBecomeActive, use applicationDidEnterBackground.

And then, the password requiere is set when the app minimizes, and not when it comes up again.

Comment: While that works, he was asking about push notifications only

Comment: He just move the push n. code of applicationDidBecomeActive to applicationDidEnterBackground, not all the code. But I think your answer Its better